# Empty lines between stacked columns in amcharts

Tags: amcharts

I'm using stacked columns in amcharts. Just like in tutorial:
https://www.amcharts.com/demos-v3/stacked-column-chart-v3/

The problem is white line in column 3 between red and green(yes, bug in the tutorial).
Is it possible to remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a known SVG rendering issue that we (amCharts) can't fix. The internal coordinates are correct but the browser's SVG rendering engine sometimes renders a gap so there is very little we can do. A workaround that usually works is to set `lineThickness` to 1 or larger in each of your graphs (assuming you have a nonzero `lineAlpha` value) to mask the white line.